# How would you simplify $\frac{\frac{6y}{y + 6}}{\;\frac{5}{7y + 42}\;}$ using LCD method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Peace to all. While in class I was taught to solve complex fractions by an "alternative method" in which you would:

1. Multiply the numerator and denominator by the LCD
2. Apply the distributive property
3. Factor and Simplify

An example: $\dfrac{4 - \dfrac 6 {x}} {\dfrac 2 {x} - \dfrac 3 {x^2}}$

1. Multiply the numerator and denominator by the LCD (x^2):

$\dfrac{4 - \dfrac 6 {x}} {\dfrac 2 {x} - \dfrac 3 {x^2}}$

2. Apply the distributive property:

$$\dfrac{x^2 × (4) - x^2 × \dfrac 6 {x}} {{x^2} × \dfrac 2x - x^2 × \dfrac 3 {x^2}}$$

3. Factor and Simplify

$$\dfrac{4x^2 - 6x} {2x-3}$$

$$\dfrac{2x(2x - 3)}{2x-3}$$

> A:2x

This example is very straightforward and simple.  However, when I put it to use it becomes very difficult. For example for the equation: $\dfrac{\dfrac{6y}{(y + 6)}}{\dfrac{5}{(7y + 42)}}$.  I get $y + 42$ as the LCD.  I'm not too confident of this because when  I begin to distribute I get very large numbers.  How would one apply this to the prior equation?

Comment: Just confirm if the edit I have made in your question is correct

Comment: @JitendraSingh Peace. I don't see that option but the edit is 100% accurate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dfrac{\dfrac{6y}{(y + 6)}}{\dfrac{5}{(7y + 42)}}$

Multiply numerator and denominator by $7y+42$

$ \dfrac{\dfrac{6y \times (7(y+6))}{y+6}}{\dfrac{5 \times (7(y+6))}{7(y+6)}} \implies \dfrac{42y}{5}$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $7y+42=7(y+6)$. Given this, both the numerator and denominator contain $y+6$.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
I don't know why the LCD method is used at all because it is clear, in this case, that.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{6y}{y + 6}}{\;\dfrac{5}{7y + 42}}
=\frac{6y}{\cancel{y+6}}\cdot\frac{7(\cancel{y+6})}{5}
=\frac{42y}{5}$$
The LCD is needed the "example" as a means of separately making the numerator factorable and the  denominator  "invertible".

$$
\dfrac{4 - \dfrac 6 {x}} {\dfrac 2 {x} - \dfrac 3 {x^2}}
=\dfrac{\dfrac{4x-6}{x}} {\dfrac{2x-3}{x^2}}
=\dfrac{2(\cancel{2x-3})}{x}
\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{\cancel{2x-3}}
=2x
$$

Comment: Perhaps they just like to make our lives unnecessarily difficult lol. Thank you

Comment: @יהודה
 Glad I could help. I see a lot of "answers" to questions that almost seem to avoid simple solutions that are obvious once seen. I hope my treatment of the "example" showed you why LCD should be invoked at all.

Comment: No, it did help. My professor actually stated that she disapproves of this method because of how unnecessarily uncomplicated it is.  Thanks again.